# Are all automorphisms of the Hyperfinite $II_1$ factor trace preserving on projections

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It would'nt make sense to me to have an automorphism that does'nt preserve the trace of projections as it would send a projection to something equivalent to either a proper subprojection or greater projection but I am not able to show it for an arbitrary automorphism.

Of course for inner automorphisms it's trivial.

If this does not hold would you have a counterexample?

Comment: On any factor there is a unique tracial state $\tau$. ( See, e.g. https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1971-77-02/S0002-9904-1971-12708-8/S0002-9904-1971-12708-8.pdf ). If you precompose any unit-preserving $*$-homomorphism $\theta$, then it's still a tracial state so $\tau \circ \theta = \tau$ and so $\theta$ is trace-preserving.

Comment: Oh of course, thank you that was obvious

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by westerbaan, in any II$_1$-factor the trace is unique. This follows from the fact that the values of the trace on projections are determined by the Murray-von Neumann equivalence of projections.

Namely, let $p$ be a projection. Fix $n\in\mathbb N$. Murray and von Neumann showed that there is a Division Algorithm for projections. Namely, if you choose $n$ pairwise orthogonal equivalent projections $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ with $\sum q_j=1$, then there exists $m\leq n$, pairwise orthogonal subprojections $q_1,\ldots,q_m$ of $p$, and another subprojection $r$ of $p$ with $r\preceq q_1$, such that 
$$
p=\sum_{j=1}^m q_j + r. 
$$
Since $\tau(q_j)=1/n$, it follows that $\tau(p)=m/n+\tau(r)$, with $\tau(r)<1/n$. Thus 
$$
\left| \tau(p)-\frac mn\right|\leq\frac 1n.
$$
As this can be done for any $n$, this determines the real number $\tau(p)$, just using the fact that $\tau$ is a trace.